# Python/Pandas: add value from one df to end of row in another df if there is a match

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to return the value of one column in df1 and append it to a row in a df2 if a value from the df2 is in the first.

Sample code

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
        {
        'terms' : ['term1','term2'],
        'code1': ['1234x', '4321y'],
        'code2': ['2345x','5432y'],
        'code3': ['3456x','6543y']
        }
        )
df1 = df1[['terms'] + df1.columns[:-1].tolist()]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
        {
        'name': ['Dan','Sara','Conroy'],
        'rate': ['3','3.5','5.2'],
        'location': ['FL','OH','NM'],
        'code': ['4444g','6543y','2345x']                           
         })
df2 = df2[['name','rate','location','code']]
```

To merge the "code" columns into a new column, which results in a value I want to add to the rows in the second dataframe where there is a match.

```
df1['allcodes'] = df1[df1.columns[1:]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),axis=1)
```

Now df1 looks like:

```
 terms  code1  code2  code3           allcodes
0  term1  1234x  2345x  3456x  1234x,2345x,3456x
1  term2  4321y  5432y  6543y  4321y,5432y,6543y
```

What I need to do is, if df2['code'] is in df1['allcodes'], add the corresponding value of allcodes to the end of a row in df2 where there is a match.

The end result should be:

```
     name rate location   code allcodes
0    Sara  3.5       OH  6543y 4321y,5432y,6543y
1  Conroy  5.2       NM  2345x 1234x,2345x,3456x
```

Dan shouldn't be in there because his code isn't in df1

I have looked and merge/join/concat, but as the tables are different sizes and the code from df2 can appear in multiple columns in df1, I don't see how to use those functions.

Is this time for a lambda function, maybe with map? Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df1
   terms  code1  code2  code3
0  term1  1234x  2345x  3456x
1  term2  4321y  5432y  6543y

df2
     name rate location   code
0     Dan    3       FL  4444g
1    Sara  3.5       OH  6543y
2  Conroy  5.2       NM  2345x
```

---

At the cost of space, one fast way to do this would be generate two mappings, and then chain two `map` calls.

```
m1 = df1.melt('terms').drop('variable', 1).set_index('value').terms
m2 = df1.set_index('terms').apply(lambda x: \
                      ','.join(x.values.ravel()), 1)


df2['allcodes'] = df2.code.map(m1).map(m2)
df2 = df2.dropna(subset=['allcodes']) 

df2   
     name rate location   code           allcodes
1    Sara  3.5       OH  6543y  4321y,5432y,6543y
2  Conroy  5.2       NM  2345x  1234x,2345x,3456x
```

---

**Details**

```
m1 
value
1234x    term1
4321y    term2
2345x    term1
5432y    term2
3456x    term1
6543y    term2
Name: terms, dtype: object

m2
terms
term1    1234x,2345x,3456x
term2    4321y,5432y,6543y
dtype: object
```

`m1` will map `code` to the `term`, and `m2` will map the `term` to the code group.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Never heard of melt or ravel. Time to hit the books.

Comment: @mattrweaver  `melt` is a new first class function in 0.20, and ravel is used to convert ND arrays to 1D. Cheers.

Comment: what is the ".terms" at the end?

Comment: @mattrweaver That's me accessing the `terms` column to get a series.

Comment: @coldspeed -- when I run this code, I the allcodes are doubled:                    

`     name rate location   code                             allcodes
1    Sara  3.5       OH  6543y  4321y,5432y,6543y,4321y,5432y,6543y
2  Conroy  5.2       NM  2345x  1234x,2345x,3456x,1234x,2345x,3456x`

Any idea why?

Comment: @mattrweaver I think you have duplicates? Try using drop_duplicates. If you are unable to do so, please open a new question.

Comment: @coldspeed -- when I take this code away from my example and to my larger project, I get the following error: `Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` and it comes from the line `df2['allcodes'] = df2.code.map(m1).map(m2)`  The values in the larger data set are unique. Or should I post this as a new question?

Comment: @mattrweaver yeah, it would be better to do so. See if you can provide an example that suitably reproduces this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution .

```
xx=df1.set_index('terms').values.tolist()
df2['New']=df2.code.apply(lambda x : [y for y in xx if x in y] )
df2=df2[df2.New.apply(len)>0]
df2['New']=df2.New.apply(pd.Series)[0].apply(lambda x : ','.join(x))
df2
Out[524]: 
     name  rate location   code                New
1    Sara   3.5       OH  6543y  4321y,5432y,6543y
2  Conroy   5.2       NM  2345x  1234x,2345x,3456x
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ when there is `for` `if` `apply` , it must be slow :)

Comment: @Wen -- when I run your example, the New column includes the list of codes twice, so "4321y,5432y,6543y,4321y,5432y,6543y".

Comment: @Wen -- my bad. I used your code on a separate example and didn't get duplicates. But in that sample I have some 'nan' values in the data that aren't in my data above.  Your line `xx=df1.set_index('terms').values.tolist()`: if there are 'nan' values, can you skip them so they don't end up in the list.

Comment: @mattrweaver accutually I will recommend using replace or fillna change the NaN to 'NAN' :)